# add values from two text boxes and put answer in third text box when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

The user enters numbers into textbox labeled A and textbox labeled B. User then clicks a button and the numbers in the two textboxes are added together with the result displayed in textbox labeled C. I have designed the text boxes, labels and button using html but I'm having trouble figuring out the javascript code to do the math. I have just started reading about javascript and I'm confused about the right approach to solve this. Any sample code is appreciated.

Comment: yOU SAY : `Any sample code is appreciated.`  sir, we want to see *your* sample code ... i.e "what I have so far" , rathe than "hey yall drop the code on meh"

Comment: I think you'll find this to be quite doable. look up javascript variables and browse code samples for fahrenheight conversions in JS

Comment: I'm asking for help because I don't know where to start. I havery no code to start with. Thanks

Comment: So you've exhausted your efforts. Hmm, Ok I'll help you Sir

Answer (score 1):

The trick with Javascript and Text Boxes is when you get the value from the text box it is not treated as a number.

So for example if I have the values from two text boxes stored in variables and I try to perform addition it will concatenate, or add togeather the two values.

```
var text1 = textbox.value;
var text2 = textbox2.value;

var newVal = text1 + text2;
```

In javascript we can force items to be numbers with

```
var newVal = Number(text1) + Number(text2);
```

Which means we have a numeric result as we expect.

If you are just starting out with Javascript there a number of good resources to learn - spend some time with them, SO is more helpful with explicit questions. Try [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) as a start but there are large number of resources to get you started.